# Maximum(s) of a sequence, with value determined by key function, where key returns a vector

Tags: clojure

Continuing my journey of using Udacity's python-based CS212 and translating to Clojure, I am trying to write a function that:

1. Returns all items in a sequence,
2. that are equal to the maximum of the sequence,
3. using a "key" function that returns a vector

Clojure's [max-key function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/max-key#source) does almost this, except that it requires my key to return an integer, which in this case I don't--I return a vector. With some modification, I can use the compare function to compare the vectors returned by my keying function:

```
(defn all-max-key
  "Returns a vector of x for which (k x), arbitrated by compare, are greatest."
  ([k x] x)
  ([k x y] (if (= 1 (compare (k x) (k y))) x y))
  ([k x y & more]
     (reduce #(all-max-key k %1 %2) (all-max-key k x y) more)))
```

Now, the problem is that this doesn't account for ties (where compare returns 0). In other words, all elements in my list are unique, but some may have equivalent values per my keying function. In imperative world, I might loop through the list, keeping track of my max value, comparing each element to it, and then appending / replacing a mutable list as I go.

But I feel like there has to be an idiomatic, elegant, functional way of doing this without resorting to loops. My attempts to use reduce have all resulted in nonsensical comparisons of sequences to member elements. Can anyone shine light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns a vector of the maximal items:

```
(defn maximal-key [k x & xs]
  (reduce (fn [ys x]
            (let [c (compare (k x) (k (peek ys)))]
              (cond
                (pos? c) [x]
                (neg? c) ys
                :else    (conj ys x))))
          [x]
          xs))
```

Testing at the REPL:

```
;; convoluted key function to demonstrate that vector keys are fine
user> (maximal-key #(vector (first %))
                    (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6) (list 3 6 8)
                    (list 4 7 9) (list 1 5 9))
[(4 5 6) (4 7 9)]
```

Note that `compare` may return an arbitrary positive integer to indicate its first argument is greater than the second -- hence the `pos?` in place of `== 1`.

Comment: This was exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for. I'm not sure I still understand it fully--particularly how [ys x] is destructured, but I think that is just going to take me some noodling. peek is new for me as well. Thank you for the reducing code that deals with collections. So many of the examples I see are trivial (reduce + [1 2 3]) kinds of things.

Comment: Happy to hear that! There's actually no destructuring involved here, `[ys x]` is the parameter vector of the reduction function. At each step of the reduction, the `ys` argument will hold the current value of the accumulator -- a vector of all items maximal in the fragment of the input processed so far -- and `x` will be the item currently being processed. If the current element is greater the last (and hence all) of the previously maximal elements, it is used to initialize a new accumulator; if it compares equal, it is added to the accumulator; otherwise it is discarded.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thank you for the explanation!